# Show dropdown menu only when start typing in R Shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny

With Shiny when you use `SelectizeInput` with `multiple = TRUE`:

1. a dropdown menu with all the element appears as soon as you are in
   that box.
2. Then, when you start typing, the result in the dropdown
   menu are filtered depending on what you type.

When the list is very long, sometimes the point 1 is pointless. Is it possible to see the dropdown only when you start typing (only from point 2)?

Reproducible example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(
        inputId = "TEST", label = NULL, choices = c("aa","ab","ac","dd","de","zzz"),
        multiple = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {          
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectizeInput` has an *options* argument, which is a list of parameters to initialize the selectize input. One of these options is `openOnFocus` which is

> Show the dropdown immediately when the control receives focus.

Turning off `openOnFocus` solves the issue.

```
 selectizeInput(
    inputId = "TEST", label = NULL, choices = c("aa","ab","ac","dd","de","zzz"),
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list(openOnFocus = FALSE,
                   #If the user write aa then delete it all, the complete list will show up again, 
                   #use maxOptions to solve this issue
                   maxOptions = 3))
```

See the full list here [selectize
/
selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md).